# What is the logic for typing an element of an array in Julia

Tags: arrays, types, julia

I want to use an array of Set of integers in Julia, but when I look a the type of each element, it is not a Set, Why ?

```
typeof(fill(Set{Int64}[],3)[2])
```

returns

```
 Array{Set{Int64},1}
```

and not

```
 Set{Int64}
```

If I used primitive types, for example,

```
 typeof([1,2][1]) # returns Int64
```

but

```
 typeof([Set{Int64}[],Set{Int64}[]][1]) # returns Array{Set{Int64},1}
```

Why there is a Array enclosing Set{Int64}

Answer (score 5):

You wrote
`typeof(fill(Set{Int64}[],3)[2])`

`Set{Int}[]` is another way of writing `Vector{Set{Int}}`.
Generally this way makes more sense when usd on a nonempty array construction like `Int128[1,2,3]`

You probably wanted `Set{Int}()` to get a single set.
Check `typeof(fill(Set{Int64}(), 3)[2])`

**However** this will fill the array with 3 references to the same set. So mutating one will mutate them all.
Rarely what you want.

Probably what you really wanted was:
`[Set{Int}() for _ in 1:3]`

Comment: I don't think `x = fill(Set{Int64}(),3)` fills with refs to the same set, but maybe I'm missing something. When I then do `x[1] = Set{Int64}([1,2])`, I get `x == [Set([2, 1]), Set(), Set()]`

(edited formatting)

Comment: Thanks, I was wrong using the Set constructor. you're also right, saying the references will be share using fill as in the folllowing example : ```z=fill(Set{Int64}(),2); push!(z[1],2); z # returns 2-element Array{Set{Int64},1}:
 Set([2])
 Set([2]) ``

Comment: Ah OK I see, I was not modifying the set but replacing it in my example. Always listen to Lyndon I should :)